# Troubleshooting Cloudflare 301 Redirects

Tags: dns, godaddy, cloudflare

My client has a URL they want to entirely redirect to another site (301 redirect).  This domain is purchased and managed through GoDaddy (unfortunately).  After setting up the redirect, I was getting problems because the URL does not have a SSL certificate installed.  GoDaddy charges $80/yr for SSL certificates.  I tried to circumvent this by routing traffic through Cloudflare, but my records and page rule configurations don't seem to be doing anything.

Anyone know how to do this properly?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Mind sharing screenshots of your DNS page and your Page Rules page? Also, compare what you have to [this article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules). And please include which URLs you want to forward (the exact desired behavior). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister, I added the images as requested. I'm trying to redirect all traffic from alumniengagement.com to alumninations.com (from any subpage to the homepage)